# Swing behavior on splitPane

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane

```
  JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,
             scrollPane , scrollPane2);
```

I want to do very trivial action and I it doesn't work.

Whenever I add label to either of scrollPanes - they simply don't display anything. I can display tables within panes but these are added through the constructor. Pisses a lot.

Also if splitPane only allows two components - what if I want to separate window into four parts? SplitPane of SplitPane?

Thanks for help,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might compare your implementation to this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10110232/230513) that adds a `JLabel` instance to a `JPanel` on each side of the `JSplitPane`.

[image]

Although `JSplitPane` only admits two components, you can add another `JSplitPane` to either pane in order to subdivide either side in either direction, *ad libitum*.

Comment: +1 for JSplitPane inside a JSplitPane, this is the best way to split a SplitPane into 4 parts or more. You also might consider calling .validate() and/or .repaint() to make your jlabels show.

Comment: Interesting; that make me wonder if `pack()` was omitted or the layout was used incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to call `updateUI()` after you've added your components. `JSplitPane` is really only supposed to be used for splitting into two components. If you require more, consider using a `TableView`.