# How to Correctly Set Minimum Sizes in Java?

Tags: java, swing, resize, autoresize

For a GUI application I am creating in Java, I have the following:

- A JFrame, set to have a minimum size of (300,200)
- A JSplitPane, in which lies:

  - On the left, a JScrollPane (containing a JTree) with a minimum size of (100,0) (I only want to restrict the width to 200)
  - On the right, a JPanel with a minimum size of (200,0)

The sizing does not give me any issue under the following conditions:

- Resizing the JSplitPane all the way to the left (to the JScrollPane's minimum size), and subsequently resize the window afterward
- Just resizing the window, to a certain degree

The problem occurs when I move the JSplitPane too close to the right, whereupon resizing the window the JPanel in the right of the JSplitPane fails to adhere to the minimum width I set.

I attempted setting a maximum width on the JScrollPane, which did not seem to help at all.

Is there something involving maximum sizes I must do?  Or perhaps there is a way to attach a Listener to one of the panels to force my desired behavior? Ultimately, I just want the right panel in the JSplitPane to never be less than 200px wide.

Here is an example with behavior I am experiencing:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;

public class ResizeTest
{
    private JFrame frame;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    ResizeTest window = new ResizeTest();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public ResizeTest()
    {
        initialize();
    }
    private void initialize()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        frame.setBounds(100,100,450,300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));

        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane();
        frame.getContentPane().add(splitPane);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 0));
        splitPane.setLeftComponent(scrollPane);

        JTree tree = new JTree();
        tree.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 0));
        scrollPane.setViewportView(tree);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 0));
        splitPane.setRightComponent(panel);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I'm afraid I don't fully understand the point trying to be made in the proposed solutions, except for that setPreferred() and setMinimum/Maximum() are better to be avoided.

My question in response to learning this is, *what are my options for restricting the JSplitPane divider outside of using these methods*?  **MadProgrammer** mentioned listening for the componentResized event, but I need just a little more clarification as to why.  Am I calling setDividerLocation() in response to this event?

I apologize in advance if the appended question is meant as a separate StackOverflow question entirely, I can post another and link here if necessary.

**Update 2:**

Is simply not regulating how the user chooses to size the window and having the right panel in a JScrollPane a viable option?  This looks to me like somewhat of a standard practice.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: I realize the `panel.setMinimumSize` is just for demonstration, but `tree.setMinimumSize` is a problem. [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513)?

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/), BTW.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, the method `setMinimumSize` is a suggestion to the `LayoutManager` API.  A suggestion that may be ignored.

In order to be able to even come close to supporting this, you will need to use something like a [ComponentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html) and monitor the [componentResized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html#componentResized%28java.awt.event.ComponentEvent%29) event.

The best solution I can think of is to use a `LayoutManager` that actually uses the minimum and maximum size constraints, something like `GridBagLayout`.

Use this on a "content" pane and place you're `JSplitPane` onto this (setting it's minimum and maximum size accordingly) then add the "content" pane to frame.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I'm probably missing something really obvious, but I put this little test together, I hope it has some ideas that help :P

```
public class TestFrameSize extends JFrame {

    public TestFrameSize() throws HeadlessException {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600, 600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(250, 250));

        JLabel left = new JLabel("Left");
        JLabel right = new JLabel("Right");

        Dimension pSize = new Dimension(100, 100);
        Dimension mSize = new Dimension(25, 100);

        left.setPreferredSize(pSize);
        left.setMinimumSize(mSize);
        right.setPreferredSize(pSize);
        right.setMinimumSize(mSize);

        JSplitPane pane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, left, right);

        JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        content.add(pane);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(content);

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new TestFrameSize().setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: `Window` inherits `set/getMinimumSize` from `Container`. While I'm pretty sure the OP wants to restrict the size of the frame as well, using `setMiniumumSize` will have not effect...am I wrong :P

Comment: Ha, you know what, `setMinimumSize` on a `JFrame` actually works :P

Comment: I'm wary of `JLabel#setPreferredSize()`. IIUC, `GridBagLayout` with default constraints acts like `GridLayout`. The text probably won't be truncated on most platforms, but it's a problem waiting to happen.

Comment: Yep, that's a good point (it is only a demo). Personally, I hate preferred/min/max size and would to avoid if I can

Comment: At least on macOS, calling `setMinimumSize()` on the window is the _only_ way to limit the minimum size available to the user. If you want the minimum size to be computed by a layout manager, then see the solution I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36757982/how-do-i-set-the-minimum-size-of-a-jframe-and-get-it-to-adjust-for-frame-thickne/47321273#47321273)

Answer (score 3):

In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10110232/230513), the preferred size of the content of a `JSplitPane` is initially set to a small multiple of the component's preferred size in `getPreferredSize()`. Note that the `JSplitPane` will become no smaller than the panel's minimum size, managed by the enclosed `Jlabel`.

[image]

Comment: Your example works as expected on Mac OS X, `com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel`, where the split pane's UI delegate enforces the minimum on both panes.