# How do I set the minimum size of a JFrame and get it to adjust for frame thickness?

Tags: java, swing

I am building a program and working on it on multiple operating systems. Windows 10 and Windows 7. When I set the minimum size correctly for one either Windows 10 or Windows 7 it works for that OS but messes up the other OS. Is there a way to get the setMinimumSize to adjust for border thickness? Or is there a way to get the thickness of the border on that OS? Or is there a way to get set the minimum size of the JFrame to the size it is when it opens? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't set the minimum size. It is the job of the layout manager to determine the size of a component. The layout manager will do its job on all OS.

All you need to do is add the components to your panel/frame and then use:

```
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible();
```

The `pack()` method invokes the layout manager so all the components will be sized properly.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples. I suggest you bookmark the tutorial for tutorial all the Swing basics.

> i don't want the user to be able to set the size of the frame below a certain size.

It is extremely annoying when an application tells me how small (large) I can make the frame. The desktop is my space, if I want to make it smaller (larger) then you should not care. I can then make the frame larger (smaller) later if I am missing information. Your frame design should be flexible to allow resizing.

In any case you can set the minimum by doing something like:

```
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible();
frame.setMinimumSize( frame.getSize() );
```

Comment: I do that to initially set the size but for the duration of the program i don't want the user to be able to set the size of the frame below a certain size.

Comment: Okay thanks. The reason i have it set minimum size is because the game I am creating is a set size. It uses BufferedImages for all the sprites so I don't have a way to get it to scale them in java. If you have any ideas on how to make this better I would be very appreciative.

Comment: @GnarlyNarwhal, If you can't scale the sprites then the user should probably not be able to resize the frame larger either. So you should be using `frame.setResiabale(false)` BEFORE you do the pack. Then you don't need to worry about the minimum or maximum size.

Comment: I let them make it bigger and it centers the sprites on the screen and makes a creates a border around the game. I think it's better then completely restricting them completely.

Answer (score 0):

add this method in your constructor

```
    this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width,height));
```

Answer (score -1):

I just ran into a problem like this on macOS using Java 8. I wanted the user to be able to resize the window but obey the minimum size computed by the layout manager. Unfortunately, the AWT code that controls the window size only looks at the minimum size if it has been explicitly set.

Here is the solution I came up with. I override the doLayout() method on the frame:

```
@Override
public void doLayout()
{
    super.doLayout();

    LayoutManager m = getLayout();
    if (m != null) {
        Dimension d = m.minimumLayoutSize(this);
        setMinimumSize(d);
    }
}
```

Now, every time the layout is recomputed, the new minimum size is cached as an explicitly set value, so that AWT will pay attention to it.