# Java swing UI layout name

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Hello this is driving me crazy! im using java swing and i dont know the name of the sliding thing in between the list and text area!

A name and some information on how to implement it would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It's a [JSplitPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html) (check out the link for more information). For similar questions, check out the Java Swing tutorials which can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html). Voting to close this question as being too localized.

Comment: There's a related example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10110232/230513).

Comment: The bit in-between is the "divider", but it's part of the overall JSplitPane container as *Hovercraft* says.