# the images are not loading

Tags: java, image, swing, frame, paintcomponent

The frame window is launching but the background and the foreground images are not loading and the window frame size is also very very small.
Please help me to fix the error.

here is the code posted

## Aquarium.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Aquarium extends Frame implements Runnable
{
    Image aquariumImage,memoryImage;
    BufferedImage bImage;
    Graphics memoryGraphics;
    Image [] fishImages=new Image[2];
    MediaTracker tracker;
    int numberFishes=12;
    Vector<Fish> fishes=new Vector<Fish>();
    Thread thread;
    boolean runOk=true;
    int sleepTime=110;
    Fish fish;

    Aquarium()
    {

        //set the title and assign tracker object
        setTitle("The Aquarium ");
        tracker=new MediaTracker(this);


        //add images to the tracker object to trace it


        fishImages[0]=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src\fish1.gif");


        tracker.addImage(fishImages[0], 0);

        System.out.println("fish 1 size "+Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src\fish1.gif").getWidth(null));
        fishImages[1]=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src\fish2.gif");


        tracker.addImage(fishImages[1], 0);
        aquariumImage =Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src\bubbles.gif");


        tracker.addImage(aquariumImage,0);


        setResizable(true);

        setVisible(true);

        //assign memory to the graphics and anotherImage object

        int dx=getSize().width;
        int dy=getSize().height;
        System.out.println("x value is "+dx+ " dy value is "+ dy);

        bImage=new BufferedImage(dx, dy,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);


        try
        {
        memoryGraphics=bImage.getGraphics();

        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            System.out.println(exc.getCause());
            System.out.println(exc.getStackTrace());
        }
        //create a new thread and start the thread

        thread=new Thread();
        thread.start();





        try
        {
            tracker.waitForID(0);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        setSize(aquariumImage.getWidth(this),aquariumImage.getHeight(this));



        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
            {
                System.exit(0);
                runOk=false;
            }
        });
    }


    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
        new Aquarium();
    }


    @Override
    public void run() 
    {


        //draw 4 edges of rectangle

        Rectangle edges=new Rectangle(0+getInsets().left,0+getInsets().top,
                                        getSize().width-(getInsets().left+getInsets().right),
                                        getSize().height-(getInsets().top+getInsets().bottom));


        //add fishes to the fishes vector

        for (int loopIndex=0; loopIndex<numberFishes;loopIndex++)
        {
            fishes.add(new Fish(fishImages[0],fishImages[1],edges,this));
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());

            }
        }




        while(runOk)
        {
            for(int loopIndex=0; loopIndex < numberFishes; loopIndex++)
            {
                fish=(Fish)fishes.elementAt(loopIndex);
                fish.swim();
            }

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            repaint();
        }

    }
    public void update(Graphics g)
    {
        memoryGraphics.drawImage(aquariumImage, 0, 0, this);

        for(int loopIndex=0;loopIndex<numberFishes;loopIndex++)
        {
            ((Fish)fishes.elementAt(loopIndex)).drawFishImage(memoryGraphics);
        }
        g.drawImage(bImage, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

## fish.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;


public class Fish {

    Component tank;
    Image image1,image2;
    Point location,velocity;
    Rectangle edges;
    Random random;

    public Fish(Image image1,Image image2, Rectangle edges,Component tank) {
        random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        this.tank=tank;
        this.image1=image1;
        this.image2=image2;
        this.edges=edges;           
        this.location=new Point(100+ (Math.abs(random.nextInt())%300),
            100+Math.abs(random.nextInt())%100));    
        this.velocity=new Point(random.nextInt()%8,random.nextInt()%8);
    }

    public void swim() {

        //determine the optimum velocity to make the fish swim

        if(random.nextInt()%7<=1) {
            velocity.x += random.nextInt() % 4 ;
            velocity.x = Math.min(velocity.x, 8);
            velocity.x = Math.max(velocity.x, -8);
            velocity.y += random.nextInt() % 4;             
            velocity.y =  Math.min(velocity.y, 8);
            velocity.y = Math.max(velocity.y, -8);
        }

        //add the velocity to the location of the fish to make it move

        location.x += velocity.x;
        location.y += velocity.y;

        if(location.x < edges.x) {
            location.x=edges.x;
            velocity.x = -velocity.x;
        }

        if((location.x + image1.getWidth(tank)) > (edges.x + edges.width)) {
            location.x = edges.x + edges.width - image1.getWidth(tank);
            velocity.x = -velocity.x;
        }

        if(location.y < edges.y) {
            location.y = edges.y;
            velocity.y = -velocity.y;
        }

        if((location.y + image1.getHeight(tank)) > (edges.y + edges.height)) {
            location.y = edges.y + edges.height - image1.getHeight(tank);
            velocity.y = -velocity.y;
        }
    }

    public void drawFishImage(Graphics g) {
        if(velocity.x < 0) {
                g.drawImage(image1,location.x,location.y,tank);             
        }           
        else {
            g.drawImage(image2, location.x, location.y, tank);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should simplify your example to the shortest possible one that still demonstrates the problem. And you probably should avoid Threads for what you're doing. Just call invalidate() in your paint method when you're done painting.

Comment: I see something wrong in your code, in the sense that you using a single backslash for specifying path like **"src\fish1.gif""*, either you provide two backslashes like **"src\\fish1.gif"** or a single forward slash (better of the two), like **"src/fish1.gif"**

Comment: @Jagdeep : You are MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILIING :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm sorry to say this, but there are simply so many things wrong with your code...

Lets start with:

- DON'T override any of the `paint` methods of a top level container.  To start with, none of the top level containers are double buffered.
- Use light weight components instead of heavy weight components (use `JFrame` instead of `Frame`, use `JPanel` instead of `Panel`)...
- Use `JPanel` as your painting surface instead of the `Frame`, for the same reasons as stated above...
- As mentioned, you're thread code was doing nothing (`new Thread().start()`).
- You had no paint code to actually paint the fishies onto the screen (yes your fish had paint code, but nothing was calling it).
- You random number generator doesn't work.  I got all the fish to swim exactly in the same place...
- You're image loading code is wrong.  Use [`ImageIO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) instead
- Don't store the rectangle reference directly.  The problem is, if the window is resized, the available bounds for the fish to swim in will change, even if they are contained to within the bounds of the aquarium, it's possible for the location of the aquarium to have changed.
- As mentioed, you image paths are incorrect.  You never include `src` in any path.  Once deployed, the `src` path will no longer exist.

Here is my take...

[image: Fishies]

### Aquarium

```
public class Aquarium extends JPanel {

    public static final int NUMNBER_OF_FISHIES = 12;

    private BufferedImage masterFish;
    private Vector<Fish> fishes = new Vector<Fish>(NUMNBER_OF_FISHIES);
    private int sleepTime = 110;

    public Aquarium() {

        //set the title and assign tracker object

        try {
            masterFish = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/gnome_panel_fish.png"));
        } catch (IOException iOException) {
            iOException.printStackTrace();
        }

        // This is a little cheat which means you only ever need one fish image
        // Basically it will flip the master along it's horizontal axies ;)
        BufferedImage flippedMaster = new BufferedImage(masterFish.getWidth(), masterFish.getHeight(), masterFish.getType());
        Graphics2D g2d = flippedMaster.createGraphics();
        g2d.setTransform(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(-1, 1));
        g2d.drawImage(masterFish, -masterFish.getWidth(), 0, this);
        g2d.dispose();

        for (int index = 0; index < NUMNBER_OF_FISHIES; index++) {
            fishes.add(new Fish(masterFish, flippedMaster, this));
        }

        Thread background = new Thread(new Background());
        background.setDaemon(true);
        background.start();

    }

    public static void main(String ar[]) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) {
                } catch (InstantiationException instantiationException) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException illegalAccessException) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException unsupportedLookAndFeelException) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("The Aquarium ");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new Aquarium());
                frame.setSize(400, 400);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        for (Fish fish : fishes) {
            fish.drawFishImage(g);
        }

    }

    protected class Background implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (true) {

                for (Fish fish : fishes) {
                    fish.swim();
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Fish

```
public class Fish {

    private Component tank;
    private Image image1, image2;
    private Point location, velocity;
    private Random random;

    public Fish(Image image1, Image image2, Component tank) {
        random = new Random();
        this.tank = tank;
        this.image1 = image1;
        this.image2 = image2;
        this.location = new Point(
                        100 + (Math.abs(random.nextInt()) % 300),
                        100 + Math.abs(random.nextInt()) % 100);
        this.velocity = new Point(random.nextInt() % 8, random.nextInt() % 8);
        System.out.println(location);
    }

    public void swim() {

        Rectangle edges = tank.getBounds();

        //determine the optimum velocity to make the fish swim

        if (random.nextInt() % 7 <= 1) {
            velocity.x += random.nextInt() % 4;
            velocity.x = Math.min(velocity.x, 8);
            velocity.x = Math.max(velocity.x, -8);
            velocity.y += random.nextInt() % 4;
            velocity.y = Math.min(velocity.y, 8);
            velocity.y = Math.max(velocity.y, -8);
        }

        //add the velocity to the location of the fish to make it move

        location.x += velocity.x;
        location.y += velocity.y;

        if (location.x < edges.x) {
            location.x = edges.x;
            velocity.x = -velocity.x;
        }

        if ((location.x + image1.getWidth(tank)) > (edges.x + edges.width)) {
            location.x = edges.x + edges.width - image1.getWidth(tank);
            velocity.x = -velocity.x;
        }

        if (location.y < edges.y) {
            location.y = edges.y;
            velocity.y = -velocity.y;
        }

        if ((location.y + image1.getHeight(tank)) > (edges.y + edges.height)) {
            location.y = edges.y + edges.height - image1.getHeight(tank);
            velocity.y = -velocity.y;
        }
    }

    public void drawFishImage(Graphics g) {
        if (velocity.x < 0) {
            g.drawImage(image1, location.x, location.y, tank);
        } else {
            g.drawImage(image2, location.x, location.y, tank);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jagdeep : In simpler terms use Swing not AWT :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining it in such a beautiful way.
I never mind if any one finds out error in me or my work as it always helps to improve.
I am using awt and not swing because I learning this.
once it start working I will change it to Swings and will use other things along

Comment: @Jagdeep Just beware the AWT doesn't provide double buffering, so it's likely to flicker.

Answer (score 4):

Among the several problems with your code, two stand out:

- You create a new `Thread` whose `Runnable` "method does nothing and returns." Instead, supply your implementation in the constructor:

  ```
  //create a new thread and start the thread
  thread = new Thread(this);
  thread.start();
  ```
- You have tagged you question [swing](/questions/tagged/swing), whose objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). Instead of `Runnable`, use an instance of `javax.Swing.Timer`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8616169/230513).

Addendum: Your drawing surface should be a `JComponent` such as `JPanel`. As it contain no components itself, you can override `getPreferredSize()` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10110232/230513) and `pack()` the enclosing `Window` to get the size right.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you seem to be using relative path. As a test, use hard-coded path. Once it is working, you can change it your context.

Comment: @trashgod : But the OP is providing only a single backslash, won't the OP needs to provide two backslash or else a single forward slash for specifying paths ?