# Java Bouncing Ball

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to write a Java application which draws multiple balls on screen which bounce off of the edges of the frame. I can successfully draw one ball. However when I add the second ball it overwrites the initial ball that I have drawn. The code is:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Ball extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    List<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<Ball>();   
Color color;
int diameter;
long delay;
private int x;
private int y;
private int vx;
private int vy;

public Ball(String ballcolor, int xvelocity, int yvelocity) {
    if(ballcolor == "red") {
        color = Color.red;
    }
    else if(ballcolor == "blue") {
        color = Color.blue;
    }
    else if(ballcolor == "black") {
        color = Color.black;
    }
    else if(ballcolor == "cyan") {
        color = Color.cyan;
    }
    else if(ballcolor == "darkGray") {
        color = Color.darkGray;
    }
    else if(ballcolor == "gray") {
        color = Color.gray;
    }
    else if(ballcolor == "green") {
        color = Color.green;
    }
    else if(ballcolor == "yellow") {
        color = Color.yellow;
    }
    else if(ballcolor == "lightGray") {
        color = Color.lightGray;
    }
    else if(ballcolor == "magenta") {
        color = Color.magenta;
    }
    else if(ballcolor == "orange") {
        color = Color.orange;
    }
    else if(ballcolor == "pink") {
        color = Color.pink;
    }
    else if(ballcolor == "white") {     
        color = Color.white;
    }
    diameter = 30;
    delay = 40;
    x = 1;
    y = 1;
    vx = xvelocity;
    vy = yvelocity;
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g.setColor(color);
    g.fillOval(x,y,30,30); //adds color to circle
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g2.drawOval(x,y,30,30); //draws circle
}

public void run() {
    while(isVisible()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("interrupted");
        }
        move();
        repaint();
    }
}

public void move() {
    if(x + vx < 0 || x + diameter + vx > getWidth()) {
        vx *= -1;
    }
    if(y + vy < 0 || y + diameter + vy > getHeight()) {
        vy *= -1;
    }
    x += vx;
    y += vy;
}

private void start() {
    while(!isVisible()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(25);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
    thread.start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Ball ball1 = new Ball("red",3,2);
    Ball ball2 = new Ball("blue",6,2);
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(ball1);
    f.getContentPane().add(ball2);
    f.setSize(400,400);
    f.setLocation(200,200);
    f.setVisible(true);
    new Thread(ball1).start();
    new Thread(ball2).start();
}
}
```

I wanted to create a List of balls and then cycle through drawing each of the balls but I'm still having trouble adding both balls to the Content Pane.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you allowed to change the constructor parameters for `Ball`?

Comment: Yes I just need to draw multiple bouncing balls, that's the only requirement.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I would suggest changing the parameters of your constructor to just accept a `Color` object rather than a `String` and having to parse it with that ridiculous if-else statement. (i.e. `public Ball(Color ballColor, ...) { color = ballColor; ... }`

Comment: Thanks, great suggestion. Added it to my code.

Comment: See also the examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9849950/230513).

Comment: A [JavaFX bouncy ball program](https://gist.github.com/james-d/8327842).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### With your current approach...

- The main problem I can see is that you are placing two opaque components on top of each other...actually you may find you're circumventing one of them for the other...
- You should be using a `null` layout manager, otherwise it will take over and layout your balls as it sees fit.
- You need to ensure that you are controlling the size and location of the ball pane.  This means you've taken over the role as the layout manager...
- You need to randomize the speed and location of the balls to give them less chances of starting in the same location and moving in the same location...
- Only update the `Ball` within the context of the EDT.
- You don't really need the X/Y values, you can use the panels.

.

```
public class AnimatedBalls {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AnimatedBalls();
    }

    public AnimatedBalls() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new Balls());
                frame.setSize(400, 400);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Balls extends JPanel {

        public Balls() {
            setLayout(null);
            // Randomize the speed and direction...
            add(new Ball("red", 10 - (int) Math.round((Math.random() * 20)), 10 - (int) Math.round((Math.random() * 20))));
            add(new Ball("blue", 10 - (int) Math.round((Math.random() * 20)), 10 - (int) Math.round((Math.random() * 20))));
        }
    }

    public class Ball extends JPanel implements Runnable {

        Color color;
        int diameter;
        long delay;
        private int vx;
        private int vy;

        public Ball(String ballcolor, int xvelocity, int yvelocity) {
            if (ballcolor == "red") {
                color = Color.red;
            } else if (ballcolor == "blue") {
                color = Color.blue;
            } else if (ballcolor == "black") {
                color = Color.black;
            } else if (ballcolor == "cyan") {
                color = Color.cyan;
            } else if (ballcolor == "darkGray") {
                color = Color.darkGray;
            } else if (ballcolor == "gray") {
                color = Color.gray;
            } else if (ballcolor == "green") {
                color = Color.green;
            } else if (ballcolor == "yellow") {
                color = Color.yellow;
            } else if (ballcolor == "lightGray") {
                color = Color.lightGray;
            } else if (ballcolor == "magenta") {
                color = Color.magenta;
            } else if (ballcolor == "orange") {
                color = Color.orange;
            } else if (ballcolor == "pink") {
                color = Color.pink;
            } else if (ballcolor == "white") {
                color = Color.white;
            }
            diameter = 30;
            delay = 100;

            vx = xvelocity;
            vy = yvelocity;

            new Thread(this).start();

        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

            int x = getX();
            int y = getY();

            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillOval(0, 0, 30, 30); //adds color to circle
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g2.drawOval(0, 0, 30, 30); //draws circle
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(30, 30);
        }

        public void run() {

            try {
                // Randamize the location...
                SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int x = (int) (Math.round(Math.random() * getParent().getWidth()));
                        int y = (int) (Math.round(Math.random() * getParent().getHeight()));

                        setLocation(x, y);
                    }
                });
            } catch (InterruptedException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }

            while (isVisible()) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(delay);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("interrupted");
                }

                try {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            move();
                            repaint();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (InterruptedException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void move() {

            int x = getX();
            int y = getY();

            if (x + vx < 0 || x + diameter + vx > getParent().getWidth()) {
                vx *= -1;
            }
            if (y + vy < 0 || y + diameter + vy > getParent().getHeight()) {
                vy *= -1;
            }
            x += vx;
            y += vy;

            // Update the size and location...
            setSize(getPreferredSize());
            setLocation(x, y);

        }
    }
}
```

The "major" problem with this approach, is each `Ball` has it's own `Thread`.  This is going to eat into your systems resources real quick as you scale the number of balls up...

### A Different Approach

As started by Hovercraft, you're better off creating a container for the balls to live in, where the balls are not components but are "virtual" concepts of a ball, containing enough information to make it possible to bounce them off the walls...

[image]

```
public class SimpleBalls {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimpleBalls();
    }

    public SimpleBalls() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Spot");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                Balls balls = new Balls();
                frame.add(balls);
                frame.setSize(400, 400);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                new Thread(new BounceEngine(balls)).start();

            }
        });
    }

    public static int random(int maxRange) {
        return (int) Math.round((Math.random() * maxRange));
    }

    public class Balls extends JPanel {

        private List<Ball> ballsUp;

        public Balls() {
            ballsUp = new ArrayList<Ball>(25);

            for (int index = 0; index < 10 + random(90); index++) {
                ballsUp.add(new Ball(new Color(random(255), random(255), random(255))));
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            for (Ball ball : ballsUp) {
                ball.paint(g2d);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        public List<Ball> getBalls() {
            return ballsUp;
        }
    }

    public class BounceEngine implements Runnable {

        private Balls parent;

        public BounceEngine(Balls parent) {
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            int width = getParent().getWidth();
            int height = getParent().getHeight();

            // Randomize the starting position...
            for (Ball ball : getParent().getBalls()) {
                int x = random(width);
                int y = random(height);

                Dimension size = ball.getSize();

                if (x + size.width > width) {
                    x = width - size.width;
                }
                if (y + size.height > height) {
                    y = height - size.height;
                }

                ball.setLocation(new Point(x, y));

            }

            while (getParent().isVisible()) {

                // Repaint the balls pen...
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getParent().repaint();
                    }
                });

                // This is a little dangrous, as it's possible
                // for a repaint to occur while we're updating...
                for (Ball ball : getParent().getBalls()) {
                    move(ball);
                }

                // Some small delay...
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }

            }

        }

        public Balls getParent() {
            return parent;
        }

        public void move(Ball ball) {

            Point p = ball.getLocation();
            Point speed = ball.getSpeed();
            Dimension size = ball.getSize();

            int vx = speed.x;
            int vy = speed.y;

            int x = p.x;
            int y = p.y;

            if (x + vx < 0 || x + size.width + vx > getParent().getWidth()) {
                vx *= -1;
            }
            if (y + vy < 0 || y + size.height + vy > getParent().getHeight()) {
                vy *= -1;
            }
            x += vx;
            y += vy;

            ball.setSpeed(new Point(vx, vy));
            ball.setLocation(new Point(x, y));

        }
    }

    public class Ball {

        private Color color;
        private Point location;
        private Dimension size;
        private Point speed;

        public Ball(Color color) {

            setColor(color);

            speed = new Point(10 - random(20), 10 - random(20));
            size = new Dimension(30, 30);

        }

        public Dimension getSize() {
            return size;
        }

        public void setColor(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

        public void setLocation(Point location) {
            this.location = location;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public Point getLocation() {
            return location;
        }

        public Point getSpeed() {
            return speed;
        }

        public void setSpeed(Point speed) {
            this.speed = speed;
        }

        protected void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {

            Point p = getLocation();
            if (p != null) {
                g2d.setColor(getColor());
                Dimension size = getSize();
                g2d.fillOval(p.x, p.y, size.width, size.height);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Because this is driven by a single thread, it is much more scalable.

You can also check out [the images are not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642852/the-images-are-not-loading/12648265#12648265) which is a similar question ;)

Comment: hey, how would you solve this "This is a little dangerous, as it's possible for a repaint to occur while we're updating..." thing in the second example? I tried checking for null but as the ball at this point isn't really null anymore this doesn't help much. Any ideas?

Comment: You have two choices, either synchronise around the balls list or use a BufferedStrategy and take control of the painting process

Comment: @AdamsonJeremiah Goid, because it’s shockingly hot here ... oh, wait not that type of fan 

Comment: Regarding the "dangerous repaint" as discussed in the comments above, couldn't we also just add a boolean flag 'allowRepaint' in PanelBalls and let move() set it to false in its first line and set it back to true in its last line of code?

Comment: @SeekAndDestroy You have to ensure that the flag was set in such away that would ensure that the proper thread synchronisation was maintained (so you don't end up with dirty reads) - the fact is, you gain less through using multiple threads, with the additional overheads of synchronisation, thread locks and waits then you would from using a single timer/thread. Because painting can occur at anytime, you also run the risk of "freezing" the UI

Answer (score 8):

You need to use two completely distinct classes here -- one for BallContainer which extends JPanel and is the component that draws the Balls, and another for Ball which does not extend anything but rather holds the coordinates and Color of a Ball. BallContainer should hodl a `List<Ball>` that it iterates through when it moves them and when it paints them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I understand correctly I'd create the list of balls and loop through the list, drawing each ball. Would I just call the paintComponent function that is still a part of the Ball class? I'm fairly new to Java and I've had some problems invoking functions in separate classes.

Comment: @nomad: Again, if I were to code this, Ball wouldn't have a paintComponent method since it's not a component. I'd give it a `draw(Graphics g)` method, and I'd iterate through my Ball List in the BallContainer's `paintComponent(...)` method, calling each Ball's `draw(g)` method inside of the loop.

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do is augment your `paintComponent` method.

Instead of just drawing one ball, you need to loop through them all, and draw each one.

Example:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    for (Ball b: balls) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval(x,y,30,30); //adds color to circle
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.drawOval(x,y,30,30); //draws circle
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
package BouncingBallApp.src.copy;
import java.awt.*;


public class Ball {
    private Point location;
    private int radius;
    private Color color;
    private int dx, dy;
    //private Color[] ballArr;

    public Ball(Point l, int r, Color c){
        location = l;
        radius = r;
        color = c;
    }

    public Ball(Point l, int r){
        location = l;
        radius = r;
        color = Color.RED;

    }

    public Point getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Point location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public int getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;

    }

    public void setMotion(int dx, int dy){
        this.dx = dx;
        this.dy = dy;
    }

    public void move(){
        location.translate(dx, dy);
    }

    public void moveTo(int x, int y){
        location.move(x, y);
    }

    public void paint (Graphics g) {
        g.setColor (color);
        g.fillOval (location.x-radius, location.y-radius, 2*radius, 2*radius);
    }

    public void reclectHoriz() {
        dy = -dy;       
    }   

    public void reclectVert() {
        dx = -dx;       
    }
}







package BouncingBallApp.src.copy;

public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFrame frm = new MyFrame(10);
        frm.setVisible(true);           

        for (int i=0; i<1000; i++){
            frm.stepTheBall();
        }
    }
}





package BouncingBallApp.src.copy;


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    public final int FRAMEWIDTH = 600;
    public final int FRAMEHEIGHT = 400;

    private Ball[] ballArr;

    private Random random =new Random ();
    private Color[] colors={Color.RED,Color.blue,Color.yellow}; 
    private int ballCnt;

    public MyFrame(int ballCnt){
        super();
        setSize(FRAMEWIDTH, FRAMEHEIGHT);
        setTitle("My Bouncing Ball Application");

        ballArr = new Ball[ballCnt];
        this.ballCnt = ballCnt;
         int c;

        for (int i=0; i < ballCnt; i++){
            int bcn =random.nextInt(colors.length);
            Color ballcolor=colors[bcn];
            ballArr[i] = new Ball(new Point(50,50),c=(int) (Math.random()*10+3)%8,ballcolor);


            int ddx = (int) (Math.random()*10+2)%8;
            int ddy = (int) (Math.random()*10+2)%8;         
            ballArr[i].setMotion(ddx, ddy); 
            //c++;
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        for (int i=0; i < ballCnt; i++){
            ballArr[i].paint(g);    
        }
    }

    public void stepTheBall(){
        for (int i=0; i < ballCnt; i++){        
            ballArr[i].move();

            Point loc = ballArr[i].getLocation();

            if (loc.x < ballArr[i].getRadius() ||
                loc.x > FRAMEWIDTH-ballArr[i].getRadius()){
                ballArr[i].reclectVert();
            }

            if (loc.y < ballArr[i].getRadius() ||
                    loc.y > FRAMEHEIGHT-ballArr[i].getRadius()){
                ballArr[i].reclectHoriz();
            }
        }   
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Code without explanation is hardly worth anything.