# how can i draw a circle again if it goes too far on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I am trying to make a program that starts with 7 circles at the top of a JPanel. All the circles have a random size and color. The circles start at the top of the screen and move downwards once they reach the bottom of the JPanel they should reappear at the top of the JPanel and move downwards again. I can already make the circles move downwards but I am unsure of how to draw them back at the top again. I made a method called replaceCircle to use to draw the circles back at the top of the JPanel but its not working.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class keyExample extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    private Circle[] circles = new Circle[7];

    Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
//current x and y
    double x = 150, y = 200;
    double changeX = 0, changeY = 0;
    private Circle c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, circleone;
    private int circlex = 10, circley = 0; // makes initial starting point of circles 0
    private int newCirclex = 0, newCircley = 0;
    private javax.swing.Timer timer2;
    private Random num = new Random();
    private int s = num.nextInt(8);

    public keyExample() {

        t.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        Random num = new Random();
        Random colors = new Random();

        Color color1 = new Color(colors.nextInt(256), colors.nextInt(256), colors.nextInt(256));
        Color color2 = new Color(colors.nextInt(256), colors.nextInt(256), colors.nextInt(256));
        Color color3 = new Color(colors.nextInt(256), colors.nextInt(256), colors.nextInt(256));
        Color color4 = new Color(colors.nextInt(256), colors.nextInt(256), colors.nextInt(256));
        Color color5 = new Color(colors.nextInt(256), colors.nextInt(256), colors.nextInt(256));
        Color color6 = new Color(colors.nextInt(256), colors.nextInt(256), colors.nextInt(256));
        Color color7 = new Color(colors.nextInt(256), colors.nextInt(256), colors.nextInt(256));

        int radius1 = num.nextInt(40);
        int radius2 = num.nextInt(20);
        int radius3 = num.nextInt(25);
        int radius4 = num.nextInt(45);
        int radius5 = num.nextInt(15);
        int radius6 = num.nextInt(40);
        int radius7 = num.nextInt(50);

        if (radius1 < 5) {
            radius1 = 10;
        } else if (radius2 < 5) {
            radius2 = 10;
        } else if (radius3 < 5) {
            radius3 = 10;
        } else if (radius4 < 5) {
            radius4 = 10;
        } else if (radius5 < 5) {
            radius5 = 10;
        } else if (radius6 < 5) {
            radius6 = 10;
        } else if (radius7 < 5) {
            radius7 = 10;
        } else {
        }
        c1 = new Circle(circlex, circley, radius1, color1);
        c2 = new Circle(circlex + 70, circley, radius2, color2);
        c3 = new Circle(circlex + 150, circley, radius3, color3);
        c4 = new Circle(circlex + 220, circley, radius4, color4);
        c5 = new Circle(circlex + 270, circley, radius5, color5);
        c6 = new Circle(circlex + 340, circley, radius6, color6);
        c7 = new Circle(circley + 410, circley, radius7, color7);

        circles[0] = c1;
        circles[1] = c2;
        circles[2] = c3;
        circles[3] = c4;
        circles[4] = c5;
        circles[5] = c6;
        circles[6] = c7;

        timer2 = new javax.swing.Timer(33, new MoveListener());
        timer2.start();

    }

    public void NewCircle() {
        for (int i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
            Random num = new Random();
            Random colors = new Random();
            Color color = new Color(colors.nextInt(256), colors.nextInt(256), colors.nextInt(256));
            int radius = num.nextInt(40);
            if (radius < 5) {
                radius = radius + 10;
            } else {
            }
            circles[i] = new Circle(circlex, circley, radius, color);

        }

    }

    public void replaceCircle() {
        int height = getHeight();
        newCircley = newCircley + s;
        circley = newCircley;
        Random num = new Random();
        int radius = num.nextInt(34);
        Random colors = new Random();
        Color color = new Color(colors.nextInt(256), colors.nextInt(256), colors.nextInt(256));
        if (circley > height) {
            c1 = new Circle(10, 0, radius, color);
        } else {
        }

    }

    public void createCircle() {

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, 40, 40));
        for (int i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
            circles[i].fill(g);
        }

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
        x += changeX;
        y += changeY;
        changeX = 0;
        changeY = 0;

    }

    public void up() {
        if (y != 0) {
            changeY = -3.5;
            changeX = 0;
        }
    }

    public void down() {
        if (y <= 350) {
            changeY = 3.5;
            changeX = 0;

        }
    }

    public void left() {
        if (x >= 0) {
            changeX = -3.5;
            changeY = 0;
        }
    }

    public void right() {
        if (x <= 550) {
            changeX = 3.5;
            changeY = 0;
        }
    }

    private class MoveListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Random speed = new Random();

            int s2 = speed.nextInt(12);
            int s3 = speed.nextInt(4);
            int s4 = speed.nextInt(20);
            int s5 = speed.nextInt(7);
            int s6 = speed.nextInt(5);
            int s7 = speed.nextInt(8);

            c1.move(0, s);
            c2.move(0, s2);
            c3.move(0, s3);
            c4.move(0, s4);
            c5.move(0, s5);
            c6.move(0, s6);
            c7.move(0, s7);

            repaint();

        }
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            up();
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            down();
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            right();
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            left();

        }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new keyExample();
    }
}
```

Circle Class

```
import java.awt.*;
```

public class Circle {

```
    private int centerX, centerY, radius, coord;
    private Color color;

    public Circle(int x, int y, int r, Color c) {
        centerX = x;
        centerY = y;
        radius = r;
        color = c;

    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        Color oldColor = g.getColor();
        g.setColor(color);
        g.drawOval(centerX - radius, centerY - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
        g.setColor(oldColor);

    }

    public void fill(Graphics g) {
        Color oldColor = g.getColor();
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval(centerX - radius, centerY - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
        g.setColor(oldColor);
    }

    public boolean containsPoint(int x, int y) {
        int xSquared = (x - centerX) * (x - centerX);
        int ySquared = (y - centerY) * (y - centerY);
        int RadiusSquared = radius * radius;
        return xSquared + ySquared - RadiusSquared <= 0;
    }

    public void move(int xAmount, int yAmount) {
        centerX = centerX + xAmount;
        centerY = centerY + yAmount;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with making a public `setCenter(int x, int y)` method to your `Circle` class to just put the circle back where it started?

Comment: Think about this for a second.  You have a `move` method which only knows how far the object should be moved.  It knows nothing about the container it's within.  You have a `Circle` pass which provides no information about where or how big it is.  So no one can actually determine if the a given `Circle` has past beyond the available container space...

Comment: I see what you are saying and that is one of the problems I could not fix. I am not sure how to connect the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better solution would be providing the `Circle` with some means to determine what it should do when it moves out of bounds, however, the code is so convoluted I used this instead...

Start by adding a `getBounds` method to your `Circle` class...

```
public Rectangle getBounds() {
    int x = centerX - radius;
    int y = centerY - radius;
    return new Rectangle(x, y, radius * 2, radius * 2);
}
```

This will provide information about how big and where the circle is...

Next, in your `MoveListener`, add a `checkBounds` method...

```
public void checkBounds(Circle circle) {
    int height = getHeight();
    Rectangle bounds = circle.getBounds();

    if (bounds.y + bounds.height > height) {
        circle.move(0, -(height) + bounds.height);
    }
}
```

This will be used to determine if a given `Circle` has moved beyond the bounds of the viewable area...

Next, in your `MoveListener`'s `actionPerformed` method, check each circle...

```
c1.move(0, s);
checkBounds(c1);
```

As so on...

**Updated with quick and fast example**

So, this is quick and fast example of what I've being trying to get to...

[image: Drop Circles]

This uses an `ArrayList` as the primary container for the `Circles`, but it wouldn't take much to change it to use an array (in fact, some parts would become easier)....

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class DropCircles {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DropCircles();
    }

    public DropCircles() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        protected static final int MAX_CIRCLES = 7;
        private List<Circle> circles;
        private Random rnd = new Random();

        public TestPane() {
            circles = new ArrayList<>(MAX_CIRCLES);
            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    while (circles.size() < MAX_CIRCLES) {
                        circles.add(createCircle());
                    }

                    List<Circle> purge = new ArrayList<>(MAX_CIRCLES);
                    for (Circle circle : circles) {
                        Point p = circle.getLocation();
                        p.y += circle.getYDelta();
                        if (p.y > getHeight()) {
                            purge.add(circle);
                        } else {
                            circle.setLocation(p);
                        }
                    }
                    circles.removeAll(purge);

                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        protected Circle createCircle() {

            int x = rnd.nextInt(getWidth());
            int radius = 5 + rnd.nextInt(45);
            int speed = 1 + rnd.nextInt(8);

            if (x + radius > getWidth()) {
                x = getWidth() - radius;
            }

            Circle circle = new Circle(radius, new Color(rnd.nextInt(255), rnd.nextInt(255), rnd.nextInt(255)));
            circle.setLocation(x, 0);
            circle.setYDelta(speed);

            return circle;

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            for (Circle circle : circles) {
                circle.paint(g);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

    public static class Circle {

        private final int radius;
        private final Color color;
        private int x;
        private int y;

        private int yDelta;

        public Circle(int radius, Color color) {
            this.radius = radius;
            this.color = color;
        }

        public void setLocation(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public void setLocation(Point p) {
            setLocation(p.x, p.y);
        }

        public Point getLocation() {
            return new Point(x, y);            
        }

        public void setYDelta(int yDelta) {
            this.yDelta = yDelta;
        }

        public int getYDelta() {
            return yDelta;
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillOval(x, y, radius, radius);
        }

    }

}
```

Basically what happens is, as a `Circle` leaves the viewable area, it is removed from the "list" and on the next tick (of the `Timer`), a new `Circle` is created to ensure that there is always seven circles on the screen (or there abouts).

If you were to use an array.  You could simply create a new `Circle` in the movement loop at the index position of the current `Circle`, effectivly replacing it...

Comment: thanks for the help but would it also work if I found the Y value of a moving circle and made a new circle appear at the top when the Y value was higher than the height of JPanel.

Comment: The concept is the same, but the problem you know have, is you don't which circle you are dealing with...so how to replace it in the array, but you seem to have abandoned the array, so your in double trouble...

Comment: cant I find the Y value of the first circle I make which is called c1 so that when it goes too far I just make a new one. I tried using the array but it got a bit too complicated when I had to find the Y value of any of the random circles because I want a new random circle to appear at the top where the old circle was. So if one circle starts on the middle of the screen when it goes down to far a new circle will appear on the same x value

Comment: What happens if two or more circles have the same `y` position?  My personal approach would be to use some kind of `Stack`, so that when an object moved beyond the containers bounds, you would simply `pop` it off the stack.  You would then have some mechanism that would check the size of the stack and fill it back up to the required limit with new circles

Comment: I see your point but I think my idea could work if I make different variables for each circle. They will all be set to zero but they will be called differently so if I checked the Y value of circle c1 I could look for Yone. I think doing this will let me check variable Yone and see if it went too far and if it did then I would make a new circle. the only problem I have is knowing how to make a variable hold the changing Y value of each circle

Comment: And when you need to add more or less circles.  You are digging yourself into an ever deeper hole.  You started out wanting to use an array, but now you have these instance variables instead...

Comment: I only want to keep 7 circles on the screen at the same time. That is why I think I could use an if statement for each circle to continue to make a new. I did want to use an array to keep making new circles and you helped me make it work but the problem I had was making a new circle appear when one of the circles reached the bottom of the screen. I wasn't sure how to use the array to make a new circle to replace any of the 7 circles that reached the bottom of the screen. I want the program to continue making circles until I close it

Comment: You seem to be moving backwards.  An array was a good idea.  I'm also trying to figure out why you want to re-create a new `Circle`, that could potentially break the spacing between the circels.

Comment: This is a school assignment and there are multiple steps to this assignment. The professor told us to make a small game using only shapes. He said that there could only be a max of 7 circles on the JPanel at the same time and that when one of the circles reached the bottom of the screen a new one should be made to replace the circle that reached the bottom of the screen and disappeared. The other part of the assignment is to use the square I have in my keyExample class as a spaceship and dodge the circles coming down. So if I crash with one of the circles a new one should appear at the top