# JFrame Simple Application

Tags: java, swing, timer, jpanel, paintcomponent

I am working on creating a game for fun that basically is a simplistic representation for evolution.

Essentially, when I click on my moving ball it changes color. The goal is to continuously change until it matches the background color meaning the ball is successfully hidden. Eventually I will add more balls but I am trying to figure out how to change its color upon a mouse click. I have created the moving ball animation so far.

How can I change the ball color when I click on the ball?

Code:

```
public class EvolutionColor
{
   public static void main( String args[] )
   {
       JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Bouncing Ball" );
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

       BallPanel bp = new BallPanel(); 
       frame.add( bp );

       frame.setSize( 1800, 1100 ); // set frame size
       frame.setVisible( true ); // display frame
       bp.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
   } // end main
}

class BallPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{       
    private int delay = 10;
    protected Timer timer;

    private int x = 0;      // x position
    private int y = 0;      // y position
    private int radius = 15;    // ball radius

    private int dx = 2;     // increment amount (x coord)
    private int dy = 2;     // increment amount (y coord)

    public BallPanel() 
    {
        timer = new Timer(delay, this);
        timer.start();      // start the timer
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    // will run when the timer fires
    {
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) 
    {
       System.out.println("here was a click ! ");
    }

    // draw rectangles and arcs
    public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
    {
        super.paintComponent( g ); // call superclass's paintComponent 
        g.setColor(Color.red);

        // check for boundaries
        if (x < radius)  dx = Math.abs(dx);
        if (x > getWidth() - radius)  dx = -Math.abs(dx);
        if (y < radius)  dy = Math.abs(dy);
        if (y > getHeight() - radius)  dy = -Math.abs(dy);

        // adjust ball position
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
        g.fillOval(x - radius, y - radius, radius*2, radius*2);
    }    

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html).

Don't make decisions about the state of the view in the `paintComponent`, painting can occur for any number of reasons, many you don't control. Instead, make theses decisions within the `actionPerformed` method of your `Timer`

You may also wish to consider changing your design slightly. Rather then having the balls as `JPanel`s, you create a virtual concept of a ball, which contains all the properties and logic it needs and use the `JPanel` to paint them. You could then store them in some kind of `List`, each time you register a mouse click  you could iterate the `List` and check to see if any of the balls were clicked

Have look at [Java Bouncing Ball](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022754/java-bouncing-ball/13022788#13022788) for an example

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard-coding the color (`g.setColor(Color.red);`), why not create an attribute:

```
g.setColor(currentColor);
```

Then when you click in the circle area, change `currentColor`.

Comment: Thank you! I added my mouse listener and changed the color. That way when it repaints the canvas it changes the color.