# CheckForComodification when adding items to list in another thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Hey I am modifying the class called `SimpleBalls` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022754/java-bouncing-ball/13022788#13022788) (the lower one). In the original version all the items in the list are being added by `ballsUp.add(new Ball()` before the animation takes place.

However, I want to dynamically add balls depending on some console output happening in another thread. This, of course, leads to comodification as the animation methods and me adding `Ball`s will often access the list at the same time.

I tried setting my list to `Collections.synchronizedList` but I think it only had an effect to the "upper part" of the program as, just above the `BounceEngine` class we have

```
public List<Ball> getBalls() {
            return ballsUp;
        }
```

set up for the iterations and I don't really know how to apply this there. Also, the same applies to `synchronized(list)` as neither `ballsUp` (which is the "real" List name), `Ball` nor `getBalls()` can be passed as an argument to `synchronized()`.

This is how I am adding new Balls:

```
  Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

          String s = null;
             try {
              while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
               if(s.startsWith("sttest")){
                ballsUp.add(new Ball(new Color(random(200)+54, random(200)+54, random(200)+54)));
                           }
                    }
            }
        };

        new Thread(r).start();
```

Removing the `ballsUp.add` makes the code code seamlessly.

The rest of the class is pretty much the same, the only major change is the `Thread` calling the `add`.

UPDATE: I was able to narrow down the problem a bit. No matter with what I "wrap" it, the `add` won't work if inside the while `((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null)`. Even when I only run this `add` once the ball still won't appear. If I place it below or above the `while` statement it works perfectly fine, the thread itself or the try/catch doesn't seem to be the error, it's something with the `while` loop (or its condition)

What triggers the error now is the line shown in the screenshot
[image]

- but only if the `ballsUp.add(new Ball()` is under the hood of the while loop

[image]

Also, SwingUtilities.invokeLater applied to the `for` loop in the upper picture results in no ball being drawn at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure the list is always accessed from a single thread: the event dispatch thread:

```
if (s.startsWith("sttest")) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> ballsUp.add(new Ball(new Color(random(200)+54, random(200)+54, random(200)+54))));
}
```

You wouldn't have to care about that (because it would happen automatically), if you added a ball to the list as a consequence of a UI event (like a button click): the event would be handled from the event dispatch thread directly.

Comment: Thanks so much man! Applied it to (Ball ball : getParent().getBalls()) and the balls still don't disappear but I think that's an error I made somewhere else, thanks a lot!

Comment: hey mate I updated the question, maybe you know something :/

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing here. Why don't you do what my answer tells you to do? I can't understand your picture, and I can't understand why you're trying to call paint on your balls inside an invokeLater.

Comment: I did this for testing because using invokeLater() only on the ballsUp.add(new Ball()) leads to no ball appearing at all. The class gets called, I put a print there and it works fine but the repaint doesn't seem to acknowledge the object || again, it works when put outside of the `while`. Even when I make the ballsUp.add(new Ball() run only once in the `while` it still doesn't run properly, might the invokeLater() block the "creation" of the ball?

Comment: ok bro nvm found the error. Sorry for wasting your time, will edit soon but I will keep the tick on your answer as you did most of it!

Answer (score 0):

You could return a **copy** of the list:

```
public List<Ball> getBalls() {
    return new ArrayList(ballsUp);
}
```

Comment: new ArrayList(ballsUp) iterates over the balls, potentially while the other thread adds an element to it. You would have the same problem.

Comment: unfortunately, JS Nizet is right, it basically does the same