# Canvas object is not displaying, but location is updating correctly in Java Applet

Tags: java, applet, awt, paint, java-canvas

My basic bouncing ball Applet should have a ball moving around according to the values in `loc` variable, but nothing shows up. Printing out `loc` shows that the numbers/math behind moving it around and bouncing off boundaries is indeed working as it should, but nothing shows up. Looking at examples online I didn't see why my drawing/painting code wasn't working as intended. Here's what I have, issues are probably focused about halfway down where the `Ball` object is. I posted most of the program as it does compile/run if someone will run it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Bounce2 extends Applet implements ActionListener, AdjustmentListener, Runnable
{
    //runtime variables
    boolean running = false;
    boolean kill = false;

    //buttons
    Button runbutton = new Button("Run"); 
    Button pausebutton = new Button("Pause");
    Button quitbutton = new Button("Quit");

    //text
    Label speedlabel = new Label("Speed");
    Label sizelabel = new Label("Size");

    //scrollbars
    private final int barHeight = 20, SLIDER_WIDTH = 10, MAXSPEED = 110, MINSPEED = 0, MAX_SIZE = 110, MIN_SIZE = 10;
    Scrollbar speedbar = new Scrollbar(Scrollbar.HORIZONTAL, MAXSPEED/2, SLIDER_WIDTH, MINSPEED, MAXSPEED);
    Scrollbar sizebar = new Scrollbar(Scrollbar.HORIZONTAL, MAX_SIZE/2, SLIDER_WIDTH, MIN_SIZE, MAX_SIZE);

    //drawn objs
    Ball ball;
    int size = 50;  
    private Graphics obj;
    Image offscreen = null;
    Point loc = new Point(100,100); //location of the ball
    private Thread ballThread;

    //boundaries
    int boundx = 640;
    int boundy = 400;

    //directions
    int dx = 1; //1 = left, -1 = right
    int dy = 1; //1 = up, -1 = down

    //speed
    int speed = speedbar.getValue();
    int delay;

    //initialize the applet and draw everything
    public void init()
    {
        double colWeight[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};//15 cols
        double rowWeight[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}; //10 rows
        int colWidth[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};//15 cols
        int rowHeight[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}; //10 rows
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl.rowHeights = rowHeight;
        gbl.rowWeights = rowWeight;
        gbl.columnWeights = colWeight;
        gbl.columnWidths = colWidth;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

        setBounds(0,0,480,640);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Panel controlpanel = new Panel();
        controlpanel.setLayout(gbl);
        controlpanel.setSize(640,80);

        Panel drawingpanel = new Panel(null);
        drawingpanel.setSize(640,400);
        ball = new Ball();
        drawingpanel.add(ball);
        drawingpanel.setVisible(true);

        //speed scrollbar
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 7;
        c.fill= GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbl.setConstraints(this.speedbar,c);

        //run button
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.gridx = 5;
        c.gridy = 7;
        c.fill= GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbl.setConstraints(this.runbutton,c);

        //pause button
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.gridx = 8;
        c.gridy = 7;
        c.fill= GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbl.setConstraints(this.pausebutton,c);

        //size scrollbar
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.gridx = 11;
        c.gridy = 7;
        c.fill= GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbl.setConstraints(this.sizebar,c);

        //speed text label
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 8;
        c.fill= GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbl.setConstraints(this.speedlabel,c);

        //size text label
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.gridx = 11;
        c.gridy = 8;
        c.fill= GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbl.setConstraints(this.sizelabel,c);

        //quit button
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.gridx = 6;
        c.gridy = 9;
        c.fill= GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbl.setConstraints(this.quitbutton,c);

        //add to the screen
        controlpanel.add(this.speedbar);
        controlpanel.add(this.runbutton);
        controlpanel.add(this.pausebutton);
        controlpanel.add(this.sizebar);
        controlpanel.add(this.speedlabel);
        controlpanel.add(this.sizelabel);
        controlpanel.add(this.quitbutton);

        //add listners
        speedbar.addAdjustmentListener(this);
        runbutton.addActionListener(this);
        pausebutton.addActionListener(this);
        sizebar.addAdjustmentListener(this);
        quitbutton.addActionListener(this);

        //add the panels
        add("South", controlpanel);
        add("Center", drawingpanel);

        //drawing paramaters
        obj = drawingpanel.getGraphics();
        loc = new Point(loc.x+dx, loc.y+dy);

        setVisible(true);
        validate();
    }

    public void start()
    {
        if (ballThread == null)
        {
            ballThread = new Thread(this);
            ballThread.start();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void run()
    {
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        while (!kill)
        {
            if (running)
            {
                repaint();
            }
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){System.err.println("Interrupted.");}
        }
        stop();
    }

    //class to handle animations
    class Ball extends Canvas 
    {
        public void move()
        {
            //if it will hit the right or left, flip the x direction and set it 
            if (loc.x+size >= boundx || loc.x <= 0)
            { dx *= -1; }
            loc.x += dx;
            //if it will hit the top or bottom, flip the y direction and set it
            if (loc.y+size >= boundy || loc.y <= 0)
            { dy *= -1; }
            loc.y += dy;
            setBounds(dx,dy,size,size);
        }   

        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            update(g);
        }

        public void update(Graphics g)
        {
            Graphics buffer;
            if (offscreen == null);
            {
                offscreen = createImage(boundx, boundy);
                buffer = offscreen.getGraphics();
            }

            buffer.setColor(getBackground());
            buffer.fillRect(loc.x,loc.y,boundx, boundy);
            //update loc
            move();

            //draw
            buffer.setColor(Color.black);
            buffer.drawOval(loc.x, loc.y, size, size);
            buffer.fillOval(loc.x, loc.y, size, size);

            //draw rectangles out of vector 
            super.paint(g);
            g.drawImage(offscreen, loc.x, loc.y, null);
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source == this.runbutton)
        {
            running = true;
        }
        else if (source == this.pausebutton)
        {
            running = false;
        }
        else if (source == this.quitbutton)
        {
            //kill processes
            kill = true;
            //remove listeners
            stop();
        }
    }

    public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e)
    {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        //set the new size. 
        if (source == sizebar)
        {
            //check for clipping
            int newsize = sizebar.getValue();

            // x
            if (loc.x+newsize >= boundx)
            { 
                newsize = boundx - loc.x - 1;
                sizebar.setValue(newsize);
            }

            // y
            if (loc.y+newsize >= boundy + 100)
            {
                newsize = boundy+100 - loc.y - 1;
                sizebar.setValue(newsize);
            }
            size = newsize;
        }
        if (source == speedbar)
        {
            speed = speedbar.getValue();
            delay = MAXSPEED - speedbar.getValue();
        }
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        this.speedbar.removeAdjustmentListener(this);
        this.runbutton.removeActionListener(this);
        this.pausebutton.removeActionListener(this);
        this.sizebar.removeAdjustmentListener(this);
        this.quitbutton.removeActionListener(this);
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Bounce2 extends Applet`  Swing components are double buffered by default.  Since people have already [advised you to use Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13132774/418556), I'll revisit this when you show signs of heeding the message.

Comment: @Zak Didn't you satisfied with the answers here? Please accept the answers.

Comment: @RomanC I was at a funeral, sorry. I'll accept the answer I used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is modified version of your code that is running.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Bounce2 extends Applet implements ActionListener, AdjustmentListener, Runnable
{
  //runtime variables
  boolean running = false;
  boolean kill = false;

  //buttons
  Button runbutton = new Button("Run");
  Button pausebutton = new Button("Pause");
  Button quitbutton = new Button("Quit");

  //text
  Label speedlabel = new Label("Speed");
  Label sizelabel = new Label("Size");

  Panel drawingpanel;

  //scrollbars
  private final int barHeight = 20, SLIDER_WIDTH = 10, MAXSPEED = 110, MINSPEED = 0, MAX_SIZE = 110, MIN_SIZE = 10;
  Scrollbar speedbar = new Scrollbar(Scrollbar.HORIZONTAL, MAXSPEED/2, SLIDER_WIDTH, MINSPEED, MAXSPEED);
  Scrollbar sizebar = new Scrollbar(Scrollbar.HORIZONTAL, MAX_SIZE/2, SLIDER_WIDTH, MIN_SIZE, MAX_SIZE);

  //drawn objs
  Ball ball;
  int size = 50;
  private Graphics obj;
  Image offscreen = null;
  Point loc = new Point(100,100); //location of the ball
  private Thread ballThread;

  //boundaries
  int boundx = 640;
  int boundy = 400;

  //directions
  int dx = 1; //1 = left, -1 = right
  int dy = 1; //1 = up, -1 = down

  //speed
  int speed = speedbar.getValue();
  int delay = 3000;

  //initialize the applet and draw everything
  public void init()
  {
    double colWeight[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};//15 cols
    double rowWeight[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}; //10 rows
    int colWidth[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};//15 cols
    int rowHeight[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}; //10 rows
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl.rowHeights = rowHeight;
    gbl.rowWeights = rowWeight;
    gbl.columnWeights = colWeight;
    gbl.columnWidths = colWidth;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

    setBounds(0,0,480,640);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    Panel controlpanel = new Panel();
    controlpanel.setLayout(gbl);
    controlpanel.setSize(640,80);

    drawingpanel = new Panel();
    drawingpanel.setSize(640,400);
    ball = new Ball();
    drawingpanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    drawingpanel.add("Center",ball);

    //speed scrollbar
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 7;
    c.fill= GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbl.setConstraints(this.speedbar,c);

    //run button
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    c.gridx = 5;
    c.gridy = 7;
    c.fill= GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbl.setConstraints(this.runbutton,c);

    //pause button
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    c.gridx = 8;
    c.gridy = 7;
    c.fill= GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbl.setConstraints(this.pausebutton,c);

    //size scrollbar
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    c.gridx = 11;
    c.gridy = 7;
    c.fill= GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbl.setConstraints(this.sizebar,c);

    //speed text label
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 8;
    c.fill= GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbl.setConstraints(this.speedlabel,c);

    //size text label
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    c.gridx = 11;
    c.gridy = 8;
    c.fill= GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbl.setConstraints(this.sizelabel,c);

    //quit button
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    c.gridx = 6;
    c.gridy = 9;
    c.fill= GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbl.setConstraints(this.quitbutton,c);

    //add to the screen
    controlpanel.add(this.speedbar);
    controlpanel.add(this.runbutton);
    controlpanel.add(this.pausebutton);
    controlpanel.add(this.sizebar);
    controlpanel.add(this.speedlabel);
    controlpanel.add(this.sizelabel);
    controlpanel.add(this.quitbutton);

    //add listners
    speedbar.addAdjustmentListener(this);
    runbutton.addActionListener(this);
    pausebutton.addActionListener(this);
    sizebar.addAdjustmentListener(this);
    quitbutton.addActionListener(this);

    //add the panels
    add("South", controlpanel);
    add("Center", drawingpanel);

    //drawing paramaters
    loc = new Point(loc.x+dx, loc.y+dy);
  }

  public void start()
  {
    if (ballThread == null)
    {
      ballThread = new Thread(this);
      ballThread.start();
    }
  }

  public void run()
  {
    Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    while (!kill)
    {
      if (running)
      {
        ball.invalidate();
        ball.repaint();
      }
      try
      {
        Thread.sleep(delay);
      }
      catch(InterruptedException e){System.err.println("Interrupted.");}
    }
    stop();
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);

  }

  //class to handle animations
  class Ball extends Canvas
  {
    public void move()
    {
      //if it will hit the right or left, flip the x direction and set it
      if (loc.x+size >= boundx || loc.x <= 0)
      { dx *= -1; }
      loc.x += dx;
      //if it will hit the top or bottom, flip the y direction and set it
      if (loc.y+size >= boundy || loc.y <= 0)
      { dy *= -1; }
      loc.y += dy;
    }

    public void update(Graphics g)
    {
      super.update(g);
      Graphics buffer;
      if (offscreen == null)
      {
        offscreen = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
      }
      buffer = offscreen.getGraphics();
      mypaint(buffer);
      g.drawImage(offscreen, 0, 0, this);

    }

    public void mypaint(Graphics g)
    {
      g.setColor(getBackground());
      g.fillRect(loc.x,loc.y,boundx, boundy);

      //update loc
      move();

      //draw
      g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      g.drawOval(loc.x, loc.y, size, size);
      g.fillOval(loc.x, loc.y, size, size);

      //draw rectangles out of vector
    }
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source == this.runbutton)
    {
      running = true;
    }
    else if (source == this.pausebutton)
    {
      running = false;
    }
    else if (source == this.quitbutton)
    {
      //kill processes
      kill = true;
      //remove listeners
      stop();
    }
  }

  public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e)
  {
    Object source = e.getSource();
    //set the new size.
    if (source == sizebar)
    {
      //check for clipping
      int newsize = sizebar.getValue();

      // x
      if (loc.x+newsize >= boundx)
      {
        newsize = boundx - loc.x - 1;
        sizebar.setValue(newsize);
      }

      // y
      if (loc.y+newsize >= boundy + 100)
      {
        newsize = boundy+100 - loc.y - 1;
        sizebar.setValue(newsize);
      }
      size = newsize;
    }
    if (source == speedbar)
    {
      speed = speedbar.getValue();
      delay = MAXSPEED - speedbar.getValue();
    }
  }

  public void stop()
  {
    this.speedbar.removeAdjustmentListener(this);
    this.runbutton.removeActionListener(this);
    this.pausebutton.removeActionListener(this);
    this.sizebar.removeAdjustmentListener(this);
    this.quitbutton.removeActionListener(this);
    Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It does run, but the double buffering effect seems lost. I get tons of flickering when I use it.

Comment: You are not right, double buffering is present for the Balls.

Answer (score 4):

I did the following changes in your code and could get it working fine -

First I set the initial location of ball to

```
Point loc = new Point(10,10);
```

After initializing `ball = new Ball();` added -

```
drawingpanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            drawingpanel.add("Center",ball);
```

In the run() method repaint the ball -

```
if(running){
ball.repaint(); 
}
```

In the move() method remove/comment the line -

```
//setBounds(dx,dy,size,size);
```

In the update(Graphics g) method remove/comment the lines -

```
//buffer.setColor(Color.black);
//buffer.fillRect(loc.x,loc.y,boundx, boundy);
```

The ; after if (offscreen == null); doesnt make any sense, so I commented it -

```
 //if (offscreen == null);
```

Bingo, everything was working fine ! Let me know if you are able to make it, else I will post the updated code.

Comment: Seems to work just fine, but there is a ton of flickering. You and Roman both posted the same solution at the same time, so both of your answers seem to be doing the same thing, haha

Answer (score 2):

Add a layout manager to your drawingpanel:

```
drawingpanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
drawingpanel.add("Center",ball);
```

Then, call `ball.repaint();` in the `run()` method to get into your custom update method.

Finally, remove the `setBounds(dx,dy,size,size);` statement from your `move()` method.

The final code would be this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Bounce2 extends Applet implements ActionListener, AdjustmentListener, Runnable
{
//runtime variables
boolean running = false;
boolean kill = false;

//buttons
Button runbutton = new Button("Run"); 
Button pausebutton = new Button("Pause");
Button quitbutton = new Button("Quit");

//text
Label speedlabel = new Label("Speed");
Label sizelabel = new Label("Size");

//scrollbars
private final int barHeight = 20, SLIDER_WIDTH = 10, MAXSPEED = 110, MINSPEED = 0, MAX_SIZE = 110, MIN_SIZE = 10;
Scrollbar speedbar = new Scrollbar(Scrollbar.HORIZONTAL, MAXSPEED/2, SLIDER_WIDTH, MINSPEED, MAXSPEED);
Scrollbar sizebar = new Scrollbar(Scrollbar.HORIZONTAL, MAX_SIZE/2, SLIDER_WIDTH, MIN_SIZE, MAX_SIZE);

//drawn objs
Ball ball;
int size = 50;  
private Graphics obj;
Image offscreen = null;
Point loc = new Point(100,100); //location of the ball
private Thread ballThread;

//boundaries
int boundx = 640;
int boundy = 400;

//directions
int dx = 1; //1 = left, -1 = right
int dy = 1; //1 = up, -1 = down

//speed
int speed = speedbar.getValue();
int delay;

//initialize the applet and draw everything
public void init()
{
    double colWeight[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};//15 cols
    double rowWeight[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}; //10 rows
    int colWidth[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};//15 cols
    int rowHeight[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}; //10 rows
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl.rowHeights = rowHeight;
    gbl.rowWeights = rowWeight;
    gbl.columnWeights = colWeight;
    gbl.columnWidths = colWidth;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

    setBounds(0,0,480,640);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    Panel controlpanel = new Panel();
    controlpanel.setLayout(gbl);
    controlpanel.setSize(640,80);

    Panel drawingpanel = new Panel(null);
    drawingpanel.setSize(640,400);
    ball = new Ball();
    drawingpanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    drawingpanel.add("Center",ball);
    drawingpanel.setVisible(true);

    //speed scrollbar
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 7;
    c.fill= GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbl.setConstraints(this.speedbar,c);

    //run button
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    c.gridx = 5;
    c.gridy = 7;
    c.fill= GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbl.setConstraints(this.runbutton,c);

    //pause button
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    c.gridx = 8;
    c.gridy = 7;
    c.fill= GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbl.setConstraints(this.pausebutton,c);

    //size scrollbar
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    c.gridx = 11;
    c.gridy = 7;
    c.fill= GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbl.setConstraints(this.sizebar,c);

    //speed text label
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 8;
    c.fill= GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbl.setConstraints(this.speedlabel,c);

    //size text label
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    c.gridx = 11;
    c.gridy = 8;
    c.fill= GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbl.setConstraints(this.sizelabel,c);

    //quit button
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    c.gridx = 6;
    c.gridy = 9;
    c.fill= GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbl.setConstraints(this.quitbutton,c);

    //add to the screen
    controlpanel.add(this.speedbar);
    controlpanel.add(this.runbutton);
    controlpanel.add(this.pausebutton);
    controlpanel.add(this.sizebar);
    controlpanel.add(this.speedlabel);
    controlpanel.add(this.sizelabel);
    controlpanel.add(this.quitbutton);

    //add listners
    speedbar.addAdjustmentListener(this);
    runbutton.addActionListener(this);
    pausebutton.addActionListener(this);
    sizebar.addAdjustmentListener(this);
    quitbutton.addActionListener(this);

    //add the panels
    add("South", controlpanel);
    add("Center", drawingpanel);

    //drawing paramaters
    obj = drawingpanel.getGraphics();
    loc = new Point(loc.x+dx, loc.y+dy);

    setVisible(true);
    validate();
}

public void start()
{
    if (ballThread == null)
    {
        ballThread = new Thread(this);
        ballThread.start();
        repaint();
    }
}

public void run()
{
    Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    while (!kill)
    {
        if (running)
        {
            repaint();
            ball.repaint();
        }
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){System.err.println("Interrupted.");}
    }
    stop();
}

//class to handle animations
class Ball extends Canvas 
{
    public void move()
    {
        //if it will hit the right or left, flip the x direction and set it 
        if (loc.x+size >= boundx || loc.x <= 0)
        { dx *= -1; }
        loc.x += dx;
        //if it will hit the top or bottom, flip the y direction and set it
        if (loc.y+size >= boundy || loc.y <= 0)
        { dy *= -1; }
        loc.y += dy;
//            setBounds(dx,dy,size,size);
    }   

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        update(g);
    }

    public void update(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics buffer;
        if (offscreen == null);
        {
            offscreen = createImage(boundx, boundy);
            buffer = offscreen.getGraphics();
        }

        buffer.setColor(getBackground());
        buffer.fillRect(loc.x,loc.y,boundx, boundy);
        //update loc
        move();

        //draw
        buffer.setColor(Color.black);
        buffer.drawOval(loc.x, loc.y, size, size);
        buffer.fillOval(loc.x, loc.y, size, size);

        //draw rectangles out of vector 
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawImage(offscreen, loc.x, loc.y, null);
    }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source == this.runbutton)
    {
        running = true;
    }
    else if (source == this.pausebutton)
    {
        running = false;
    }
    else if (source == this.quitbutton)
    {
        //kill processes
        kill = true;
        //remove listeners
        stop();
    }
}

public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e)
{
    Object source = e.getSource();
    //set the new size. 
    if (source == sizebar)
    {
        //check for clipping
        int newsize = sizebar.getValue();

        // x
        if (loc.x+newsize >= boundx)
        { 
            newsize = boundx - loc.x - 1;
            sizebar.setValue(newsize);
        }

        // y
        if (loc.y+newsize >= boundy + 100)
        {
            newsize = boundy+100 - loc.y - 1;
            sizebar.setValue(newsize);
        }
        size = newsize;
    }
    if (source == speedbar)
    {
        speed = speedbar.getValue();
        delay = MAXSPEED - speedbar.getValue();
    }
}

public void stop()
{
    this.speedbar.removeAdjustmentListener(this);
    this.runbutton.removeActionListener(this);
    this.pausebutton.removeActionListener(this);
    this.sizebar.removeAdjustmentListener(this);
    this.quitbutton.removeActionListener(this);
    Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
}
}
```

Comment: Interesting. It does create and move a ball, but the double buffering effect seems lost (tons of flickering), and the ball flies off the screen (but it does eventually return)