# Java - graphics paint

Tags: java, swing, oop, graphics, jframe

I'm trying to develop a Java brick breaker (like DxBall) game and I want to make the `Ball` object with its own draw method.

What I'm trying to do:

```
public class Ball {
  private int x, y, diameter;
  public void  Ball(){
    x = 0;
    y = 0; 
    diameter = 20;
  }

  public void draw(Graphics g){
    g.setPaint(Color.red);
    g.fillOval(x, y, diameter, diameter);
  }
}
```

Therefore, my game engine extends `JFrame` and its `paintComponent` method will call game objects draw method. To sum, is it proper way to do object oriented game in Java? What should my `Ball` class extend?

Comment: It depends on where do you want to apply this objects.

Comment: I want to apply these objects in my GameEngine class which is a JFrame. GameEngine does some calculations and changes my objects(Ball or Paddle) x,y or speed values and then it will call all drawable objects paint methods.

Comment: No, you cannot call a paint method, call a draw method instead.

Comment: Ok, look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13164162/canvas-object-not-displaying-but-location-is-updating-correctly-in-java-applet/13166879#13166879) example my be this help you but it needs to convert to the light objects.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to make `Ball` a graphical component, you could extend `JComponent`:

```
public class Ball extends JComponent {
    private int x;
    private int y
    private int diameter;

    public Ball() {
        x = 0; 
        y = 0; 
        diameter=20;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setPaint(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(x, y, diameter, diameter);          
    }
}
```

and simply call `repaint` when you wish to paint the component instead of a custom `draw` method.

Note: There's no return type for constructors.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Ball` class seems to look ok. It doesn't need to extend anything. You will need to pass the `Graphics` object from the `paintComponent` of your game object to the `Ball` `draw` method.

Comment: I tried to pass Graphics object to my Ball class however it failed.

Comment: The paintComponent method in the game class should call the Ball.draw(g) method. How did it fail?

Answer (score 1):

Your class is fine but I recommend extending a class. This class usually called as `Sprite` or `Action` or `GameObject` contains the basic information like

**`image (or animation), position, collision rect and some basic functions like get and set it's position, speed and some collision detection functions if you wish.`**

Some resources.

- [The Breakout game](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/breakout/)
- [GEJ - game-engine-for-java](http://code.google.com/p/game-engine-for-java/)
- [Java-Gaming.org - Java Gaming Resources](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?action=resources)

Hope they help. And to draw the object, do

```
g.drawImage(ball.image, ball.x, ball.y, null);
```

Comment: In many games, the objects would extend a class `Actor` or `Sprite` or else which would contain the basic nature of any element in the game like it's `position, image, collision rect` etc.,

Comment: I recommend extending the class. Sorry for my english.

Comment: I think you should edit more of that excellent 1st comment into your answer. It makes it more clear.  :)