# How to get horizontal scroll bars in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jfreechart

I have a panel layout issue that I can't seem to solve. I have the following code:

```
public class Test extends ApplicationFrame {
    public Test(String title) {
        super(title);

        JPanel jpanel = new JPanel();
        jpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100 * 2, 300));
        jpanel.setBackground(new Color(0xFF0000));

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jpanel);
        scrollPane.setBackground(new Color(0xFF0000));
        scrollPane.getViewport().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100 * 2, 300));

        this.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test test = new Test("Layout Test");
        test.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(test);
        test.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

to create the following layout:

[image]

When I drag the right hand side of the window and move it over into the red `JPanel` and `JScrollPane`, I'd like the horizontal scroll bars to appear on the `JScrollPane`. But currently the window just shrinks without showing the horizontal scroll bar. Is this possible?

I'd like to keep the `BorderLayout.WEST` since my use case for this is to keep a JFreeChart from stretching when I don't have a big enough chart to fill the entire window.

Comment: The `WEST` component isn't actually begin "compressed" horizontally.  In this case, I don't thing `BorderLayout` is your friend

Comment: @MadProgrammer do you have a suggestion of which layout manager would be a better option?

Comment: My gut feel is `GridBagLayout`, but I'm not yet convinced that it will server your purpose

Comment: I assume that those many setXXSize are for demonstration only :-)

Comment: @kleopatra nope - pure ignorance that setXXSize was not to be used. I'm a java ui newb in all respects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are [many reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513) not to use `setPreferredSize()`, but the critical one here is that the desired result *depends* on the preferred size of the enclosed components. In particular,

- `ChartPanel` has the default `FlowLayout` specified by `JPanel`, but the chart ignores this and adjusts to fill the space available; you can override `getPreferredSize()` to choose any desired initial geometry.
- The scroll bars of a `JScrollPane` only appear when the size of the viewport is smaller than the size of the content. `BorderLayout.WEST` and `BorderLayout.EAST` don't change, so the scroll bars never appear.

Invoking `pack()` "causes this `Window` to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents." In the example below, the frame's size is artificially reduced after `pack()` in order to cause the scroll bars to appear. `GridLayout` causes the two panels to be equal is size. Resize the frame to see the effect.

Addendum: If you want a `ChartPanel` to have a fixed size, add it to a `JPanel`; the default `FlowLayout` uses the preferred size.

[image]

```
public class ChartPanelTest {

    private static final int N = 64;
    private static final int SIZE = 400;
    private static final Random random = new Random();

    private static XYDataset createDataset() {

        final TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Random Data");
        Day current = new Day();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            series.add(current, random.nextGaussian());
            current = (Day) current.next();
        }
        return new TimeSeriesCollection(series);
    }

    private static JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
            "Test", "Day", "Value", dataset, false, false, false);
        return chart;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(createDataset());
        f.add(new JScrollPane(new JPanel() {

            {
                setBackground(Color.red);
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(SIZE, SIZE);
            }
        }));
        f.add(new ChartPanel(chart) {

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(SIZE, SIZE);
            }
        });
        f.pack();
        f.setSize(2 * (SIZE - N), SIZE - N);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: this looks to be what I was looking to accomplish. Still have to translate into the real application but the demo was super helpful. Thanks! Also nice pickup that this was for JFreeChart. :D

Comment: Was able to integrate successfully into the real application. Thanks again!

Comment: Excellent; also consider `JSplitPane`, shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10110232/230513).

Answer (score 0):

it can be done. you can declare three JPanel.
One JPanel is a contentPanel whit BorderLayout.
set at preferedSize and maximumSize of JPanel that you want a scrollbar
create a jscroolpane and its finish:
pseudo code:

```
JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayuout());
JPanel jpanel1 = new JPanel(layout--);
JPanel jpanel2 = new JPanel(layout--);
jpanel2.setPreferredSize(..);
jpanel2.setMaximuSize(..);
JScrollPane jsp = new JScroolPane(jpanel2);
contentPanel.add(jpanel1,BorderLayout.WEST);
contentPanel.add(jsp,BorderLayout.CENTER);
this.getContentPane().add(contentPanel);
```

in my example scrollbar is in center.
if you want change

```
contentPanel.add(jsp,BorderLayout.WEST);
contentPanel.add(jpanel1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: -1 for setXXSize - for reasons _not_ to do that ever, see the reference in @trashgod 's answer