# JSplitPane - split application into two?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jsplitpane

I made a Java swing application. My main class does the whole `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()` stuff.

My second class where everything is I've used:

```
JPanel container = (JPanel) getContentPane();
```

Then added all the bits by calling..

```
container.add([name of component]
```

I'd now like to get this entire 'application' into a `JSplitPane`. Hence I want my application on one side and something else on the right side.

How do I do this?

```
    public class one{
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            JFrame f = new App("main");
            f.setSize(1920,1080);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setVisible(true);
}


public class App extends JFrame {
        SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
        public App(String title) {
        super(title);
        JPanel container = (JPanel) getContentPane();

        container.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        JButton new button = new JButton("new");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        //ENTER LOTS OF CONSTRAINTS
        container.add(new, c);

        JButton next to button = new JButton("next to");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        //ENTER LOTS OF CONSTRAINTS
        container.add(new, c);

        //I HAVE LOTS OF SWING COMPONENTS AND BUTTONS about 30

}
```

I want all of this in the left of the split pane?

how do I do this?

Comment: One way is to put content into two containers (e.g. `JPanel`) and add them to a split-pane, then add the split pane to the content pane.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of current code (rather than code snippets & descriptions).

Comment: Is that better? I just wrote up some mock code to demo my point.

Comment: I can't see any reason why you should create that `one` class just to put main method inside.

Comment: the 'one' class is there to multithread the application...I think

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10110232/230513).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Don't extend from `JFrame`, you're not adding any functionality to, instead, move all you application components and logic to a separate `JPanel`
2. Create an instance of a `JSplitPane`, add the "main" panel to it, add you secondary pane to it
3. Create an instance of a `JFrame`, add the split pane to it...

**UPDATED**

[image]

```
public class TestSplitPane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestSplitPane();
    }

    public TestSplitPane() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JSplitPane pane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
                pane.setLeftComponent(new MainPane());
                pane.setRightComponent(new JLabel("On the right"));

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(pane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MainPane extends JPanel {

        public MainPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
            JButton newButton = new JButton("new");
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 0;
            c.gridwidth = 2;
            //ENTER LOTS OF CONSTRAINTS
            add(newButton, c);

            JButton next = new JButton("next to");
            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 1;
            c.gridwidth = 2;
            //ENTER LOTS OF CONSTRAINTS
            add(next, c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance you can type our a quick SSCCE for me please?

Comment: *"I just applied the methods to my code and it's worked!"* That makes a change, I mean, of course it did ;)

Comment: =]
Any reason to why; when I grade the split in the middle to the left it won't budge and resize all the swing components?

Comment: The split pane may be restricted by the panels preferred/min size

Comment: Well If I resize the whole window it scales perfectly but refuses to scale in the pane. Really not sure =S

Comment: This has to do with the layout manager begin used to layout the components. `GridBagLayout` will "size" components to there preferred size where space allows, but won't generally (unless you specify otherwise), grow the component

Comment: It is 'growing' the component though rather well. It's just refusing to shrink it!