# SIze of Jpanel inside JSplitPanel

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane

I was trying to add `JsplitPane` into my project.Requirement is i need to add two `Jpanel` inside right panel of `JSplitPane`.

so what i had done is first add `Jpanel` say it `panel1` to right panel and set `BoxLayout.Y-AXIS` and than add two panel inside `panel1`.

now in that two panel first panel have `BoxLayout` and i want the width of this panel to be of size of `panel1` but i am not able to do it.

anyone have idea how to do it?

Comment: Use a simple paint app to draft your requirement, also share the code as what you have tried by yourself.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10110232/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was trying to add `JsplitPane` into my project.Requirement is i need
>   to add two `Jpanel` inside right panel of `JSplitPane`.

When using `JSplitPane`, we should remember that it only divides the pane into two components say *Left and Right* or *Top and Bottom*. So when we again want to add more than one components in a single side of that `JSplitPane`, say in our case *Right*, it is better to use *Nesting Split Panes*. That means creating Split Panes inside Split Panes.

> so what i had done is first add `Jpanel` say it `panel1` to right panel
>   and set `BoxLayout.Y-AXIS` and than add two panel inside `panel1`.
>
> now in that two panel first panel have `BoxLayout` and i want the width
>   of this panel to be of size of `panel1` but i am not able to do it.

If you use *Nesting Split Panes*, you may not have to create an extra Parent `JPanel` what you said as `panel1`. Actually the Split Pane is used to divide the Pane into two segments. So, by using *Nesting Split Panes* you are creating another Split Pane in stead of what you were creating as `panel1` and then put your two child panels inside the two Panes created by new `JSplitPane` which is nested. So, you don't have to think about the size issue, too. I hope I could make you clear and it solved your issue.

**A simple way to achieve that by using:**

*Declaration:*

```
private JSplitPane jSplitPane1;
private JSplitPane jSplitPane2;
private JPanel jPanel1;
private JPanel jPanel2;
```

*In Constructor:*

```
 jSplitPane1 = new JSplitPane();
 jSplitPane2 = new JSplitPane();

 jSplitPane1.setOrientation(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
 jSplitPane1.setRightComponent(jSplitPane2);
 jSplitPane2.setOrientation(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);

 jSplitPane1.setTopComponent(jPanel1);
 jSplitPane1.setBottomComponent(jPanel2);
```

The above described method is the simplest to achieve what you wanted. However, without nesting the Split Pane, it is possible to use Multi Split Panes which may not be so handy. Still you can have a look at this old article at Oracle:

https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-983539

Comment: Thanks @Rakibul Islam...this is useful